# Nikon Z6 show rule of thirds grid

Tags: nikon, rule-of-thirds

On my Z6 instead of a 3x3 grid, I get a 4x4 grid.

Is it at all possible to make a change on the firmware to show a 3x3 grid instead? I've checked the settings and can't change the grid to a 3x3 anywhere.

Failing a firmware upgrade, maybe some kind of screen protector that has rule of thirds lines?

Comment: I dont think there is a in-camera solution but Im not sure. Dont know any screen protectors either but I would get a protective film and take a sharp knife to slice the lines you need into it using a ruler.

Comment: What if the OP wants to use the EVF rather than the rear screen?

Comment: OP specifically states that a screen protector with guides would be a suitable solution.  I'm unaware of any existing protector for sale with premarked guides, but it's easy enough to mark them up yourself.

Comment: How to program firmware is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: You're taking "rule of thirds" too literally.  The point is to not center subjects.  But it's not an absolute.  Sometimes it is desirable to center subjects.  Workaround: Instead of using the grid lines, use the spaces between the lines.

Comment: Thank you for your comments everyone, I figured out how I can best approximate it using the tools the camera provides. See the answer I wrote out.

Comment: I find it amazing that Nikon doesn't support the Rule of Thirds in their Grid. They even have it listed at one of their schools! https://www.nikonschool.in/Blog/BlogDetails/257/using-the-rule-of-3rds-with-nikon-cameras Come on Nikon - help us out please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've found after staring at all the available options on the screen is that I can approximate the rule of thirds using the center circle/level tool. It's good enough that if imagine where the lines cut through that circle I can use it for framing.

Image showing what I mean (lines in red drawn on):

[image]